# 1 high severity vulnerability Incorrect Comparison in axios when installing Nest

Tags: npm, axios, nestjs, npm-install

On installing nest, received warning

`found 1 high severity vulnerability run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details`

***Result on `npm audit`***

```
  High            Incorrect Comparison in axios

  Package         axios

  Dependency of   @nestjs/common

  Path            @nestjs/common > axios

  More info       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-cph5-m8f7-6c5x
```

**Why getting this issue and How to fix it ?**

Tried `npm audit fix` but not solving the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using NPM 8: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Or just upgrade `@nestjs/common` to its latest version (v8.2.6)

```
$ npm ls axios
myapp@0.0.1 /tmp/foo
└─┬ @nestjs/common@8.2.6
  └── axios@0.24.0
```